# Finding the indices of distinct elements in a vectorized manner

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vectorization

I have a list of `int`s, `a`, between 0 and 3000. `len(a) = 3000`. I have a `for` loop that is iterating through this list, searching for the indices of each elemenent in a larger array.

```py
import numpy as np

a = [i for i in range(3000)]
array = np.random.randint(0, 3000, size(12, 1000, 1000))
newlist = []

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    coord = np.where(array == list[i])
    newlist.append(coord)
```

As you can see, `coord` will be 3 arrays of the coordinates x, y, z for the values in the 3D matrix that equal the value in the list.

Is there a way to do this in a vectorized manner without the `for` loop?

The output should be a list of tuples, one for each element in `a`:

```
# each coord looks like this:
print(coord)
(array[1, ..., 1000], array[2, ..., 1000], array[2, ..., 12])

# combined over all the iterations:
print(newlist)
[coord1, coord2, ..., coord3000]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with a sample input and desired output

Comment: Edited for more clarity on the issue

Comment: Do you have any other values in the array?

Comment: I mean besides 0-2999 in `3Darray`?

Comment: There are no other values other than ints that range(0,3000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a fully vectorized solution to this, despite the fact that the resulting arrays are all of different sizes. The idea is this:

1. Sort all the elements of the array along with their coordinates. [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is ideal for this sort of thing.
2. Find the cut-points in the sorted data, so you know where to split the array, e.g. with [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and [`flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html).
3. [`split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) the coordinate array along the indices you found. If you have missing elements, you may need to generate a key based on the first element of each run.

Here is an example to walk you through it. Let's say you have an `d`-dimensional array with size `n`. Your coordinates will be a `(d, n)` array:

```
d = arr.ndim
n = arr.size
```

You can generate the coordinate arrays with [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) directly:

```
coords = np.indices(arr.shape)
```

Now [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)/[`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the data and the coordinates into an `(n,)` and `(d, n)` array, respectively:

```
arr = arr.ravel()  # Ravel guarantees C-order no matter the source of the data
coords = coords.reshape(d, n)  # C-order by default as a result of `indices` too
```

Now sort the data:

```
order = np.argsort(arr)
arr = arr[order]
coords = coords[:, order]
```

Find the locations where the data changes values. You want the indices of the new values, so we can make a fake first element that is 1 less than the actual first element.

```
change = np.diff(arr, prepend=arr[0] - 1)
```

The indices of the locations give the break-points in the array:

```
locs = np.flatnonzero(change)
```

You can now split the data at those locations:

```
result = np.split(coords, locs[1:], axis=1)
```

And you can create the key of values actually found:

```
key = arr[locs]
```

If you are very confident that all the values are present in the array, then you don't need the key. Instead, you can compute `locs` as just `np.diff(arr)` and `result` as just `np.split(coords, inds, axis=1)`.

Each element in `result` is already consistent with the indexing used by [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)/[`nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), but as a numpy array. If specifically want a tuple, you can map it to a tuple:

```
result = [tuple(inds) for inds in result]
```

**TL;DR**

Combining all this into a function:

```
def find_locations(arr):
    coords = np.indices(arr.shape).reshape(arr.ndim, arr.size)
    arr = arr.ravel()
    order = np.argsort(arr)
    arr = arr[order]
    coords = coords[:, order]
    locs = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr, prepend=arr[0] - 1))
    return arr[locs], np.split(coords, locs[1:], axis=1)
```

You can return a list of index arrays with empty arrays for missing elements by replacing the last line with

```
    result = [np.empty(0, dtype=int)] * 3000   # Empty array, so OK to use same reference
    for i, j in enumerate(arr[locs]):
        result[j] = coords[i]
    return result
```

You can optionally filter for values that are in the specific range you want (e.g. 0-2999).

Answer (score -1):

You can use logical OR in numpy to pass all those equality conditions at once instead of one by one.

```py
import numpy as np
conditions = False
for i in list:
  conditions = np.logical_or(conditions,array3d == i)

newlist = np.where(conditions)
```

This allows numpy to do filtering once instead of n passes for each condition separately.

Another way to do it more compactly

```
np.where(np.isin(array3d, list))
```

Comment: This is still a terribly inefficient way of doing it. Also has nothing to do with what OP seems to be asking.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  what I understand is that he wants to do ```np.where``` once instead of multiple runs with each eleemnt  in array . Could you clarify the OP problem  you see here ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist added another approach to check and filter all element in the same condition

Comment: OP has a list with separate coordinates for each value. You just return `np.where(x >=0 & x<3000)` but with a loop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the second approach achieves that with good efficiency I think.

Comment: I want each coord to be seperated/filtered for that specific value in a so I don't think that would work @MadPhysicist

Comment: @TeddyZ. That's what I'm trying to tell kareem.

Comment: @kareem_emad. See my answer for something more like what OP is looking for